# Stub a method but still check if it was called using mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

```
protected void function1(arg1, arg2, arg3) throws Exception {
    Object myObject = buildMyObjectUsing(arg1, arg2, arg3);
    if(SOME_BOOLEAN){
        functionA(arg1, myObject)
    } else{
            myObject.functionB(arg1)
    }
}
```

I am working with legacy code and added the void functionA to function1. I am trying to write a test now which checks to make sure that functionA gets called when SOME_BOOLEAN is true but that it doesn't get called when SOME_BOOLEAN is false.

Is there a way where I can fake out functionA so that it doesn't actually get called but I can still see that it would have been called when SOME_BOOLEAN is true? Right now functionA is broken so the tests I write keep failing because functionA throws an exception.

Again, I'm not worried about testing whether or not functionA actually works, just that it gets called.

Comment: if it is the case , your test case should only test for SOME_BOOLEAN is true, right?

Comment: I'm trying to make a test that passes only when functionA gets called because SOME_BOOLEAN was true. If functionA gets called when SOME_BOOLEAN was false then the test should fail. Does that help? I'm new to Unit testing so I may be going about everything backwards.

Comment: is functionA private?

Comment: no functionA is not private. Currently it's a protected void

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the test method, you can test a inherited class of the actual class,and you can override the funtionaA

```
final boolean[] methodCalled = new boolean[1]; 
MyClass testTarget = new MyClass()
{
   void functionA(args)
  {
    methodCalled[0] = true;
  }

};

testTarget.function1(arg1, arg2, arg3);
//assert methodCalled[0] is true
```